# python while loop range function

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, range

Why can't while loop be used on a range function in python ?

The code:

```
def main():
  x=1;

  while x in range(1,11):
     print (str(x)+" cm");


if __name__=="__main__":
    main();
```

executes as an infinite loop repeatedly printing 1 cm

Comment: The value of x never changes, so it continuously meets your "while" criterion.

Comment: Can you write your code in a code box, with proper indentation and whatnot? Look in the help section to find out how to make a code box (4 spaces or CTRL+K)

Comment: It can. You never change the value of `x` so it's always `in` the range.

Comment: What does "use a while loop on a range" even mean? If it means "iterate over the range", then the answer is "because that's what `for` loops are for".

Answer (score 9):

Simply we can use **while** and **range()** function in python.

```
>>> while i in range(1,11):
...     print("Hello world", i)
... 
Hello world 1
Hello world 2
Hello world 3
Hello world 4
Hello world 5
Hello world 6
Hello world 7
Hello world 8
Hello world 9
Hello world 10

>>> i
10
```

Comment: It is giving following error - `NameError: name 'i' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?`.

Answer (score 7):

For what you're doing, a `for` loop might be more appropriate:

```
for x in range(1,11):
    print (str(x)+" cm")
```

If you want to use while, you need to update `x` since you'll otherwise end up getting the infinite loop you're describing (x always is `=1` if you don't change it, so the condition will always be true ;)).

Comment: I imagine it's not the best performance, right? Because it creates a tuple, which isn't needed, right?

Comment: @DennyWeinberg `range(1,11)` isn't a tuple but arguments for the `range()` function.

Comment: I thought range created a tuple (returns a tuple), but thats not right. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

while just evaluates boolean (true or false).

```py
def main():
  x=1;

  while x in range(1,11):
     print(str(x)+" cm");


if __name__=="__main__":
    main();
```

In the above code `x` is initialised to `1` and it is in the `range(1,11)` so the while executed and went in loop since the condition in `while x in range(1,11):`  is satisfied every time.
To fix this, increment `x` in the *while* loop
ex:

```py
while x in range(1,11):
    print (str(x)+" cm")
    x= x+1
```